# How can I compute faster (x**2-2)%n - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = 2**1000000
n = 2**100000000
```

`(x**2-2)%n` is too slow. I found pow() but I can't use it because I can't subtract 2. `(pow(x, 2)-2)%n` and `(x*x-2)%n` are also slow. When I tested `(x*x-2)` it was fast but when I added the modulo operator it was slow. Is there a way to compute `(x**2-2)%n` faster?

Comment: could you maybe simplify it based on [modulo properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Modular_arithmetic&action=edit&section=3)? A quick look (and intuition) reveals that you do not need the `-2` for example.

Comment: I don't know the modulo properties. Can you send a link?

Comment: For a large value of x.

Comment: What is your criterion of "too slow" ? Do you have some numbers for an existing test run, and a figure that you would like to achieve ?

Comment: I run it for a minute and I didn't get a result.

Comment: 1) (a+b)mod(n)  = amod(n)+bmod(N)
2) (a.b)mod(n)  = amod(n).bmod(n)

Comment: Using the numbers you provide here, I get an answer in about 5 seconds.

Comment: I assign x to the result and then x gets bigger because I run it multiple times.

Comment: x*x-2 <n . so why %n ?

Comment: Because I assign x to the answer and I repeat the process.

Comment: if you check my answer you would be boiling the computation down to basic subtraction and an if condition @JohnnyP.

Comment: So can you edit your post ? What do you want really? : terms of the suit u0=x, uk+1 = (uk*uk-2)%n ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you running this in the interpreter? I did some testing and the main slowdown seemed to come from the interpreter trying to display the result.

If you assign the expression to a variable, the interpreter won't try to display the result, and it will be very quick:

```
x = 2**1000000
n = 2**100000000
result = (x**2-2)%n
```

**Addendum:**

I was also originally thinking along the same lines as MikeW's answer, and if you wanted *every* part of the code to be fast, you could take advantage of Python's internal base 2 representation of integers and use bitwise left shifts:

```
x = 1 << 1000000
n = 1 << 100000000
```

This comes with the caveat that this only works because `x` and `n` are powers of 2, and you have to be more careful to avoid making an off-by-one error. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/141873/8117067) is a good explanation of how bitshifts basically work, but Python is bit different than other languages like C, C++, or Java because Python integers are [unlimited precision](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex), so you can never left shift a bit completely away like you could in other languages.

Comment: Is x = 1 << 1000000 equal to x = 2**1000000?

Comment: @JohnnyP. Yes, you can test it yourself: `2**100000000 == 1 << 100000000`

Comment: @JohnnyP. Internally, *all* numbers are binary to Python. As demonstrated by the above comparison, the numbers are identical. The only difference is that using a bitshift is faster than individually doing each multiplication by 2 (I'll add a link explaining binary in a second)

Comment: It runs very fast.

Comment: @Graham and x**2, how is it with << operator.

Comment: @JohnnyP. We can understand this by comparing base 10 (our normal number system) to binary (the way computers represent data): In base 10, each place-value represents a power of 10: `1` is 10^0, `10` is 10^1, and `100` is 10^2. In binary, each place-value is a power of 2: `1` is 2^0 (1), `10` is 2^2 (4), and `100` is 2^3 (8). When a value is left-shifted (`<<`), the base binary representation's right side is padded with 0s, which is equivalent to multiplication by 2. This is like how adding 0s in base 10 is multiplication by 10: adding a 0 to `10` result in `100`, i.e. 10 times greater.

Answer (score 1):

If x is always a power of 2, and n is always a power of 2, then you can you can compute it easily and quickly using bit operations on a byte array, which you can then reconstitute into a "number".

If 2^N is (binary) 1 followed by N zeroes, then (2^N)^2 is (binary) 1 followed by 2N zeros.

```
2^3 squared is b'1000000'
```

If you have a number 2^K (binary 1 followed by K zeroes), then 2^K - 2 will be K-1 1s (ones) followed by a zero.

```
eg 2^4 is 16 =  b'10000', 2^4 - 2 is b'1110'
```

If you require "% 2^M" then in binary, you just select the last (lower) M bits, and disregard the rest .

```
9999 is       b'10011100001111'
9999 % 2^8 is       b'00001111'
```

'

Hence combining the parts, if x=2^A and n=2^B, then

(x^2 - 2 ) % n

will be: (last B bits of) (binary) (2*A - 1 '1's followed by a '0')

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: You don't need a "byte array" to do this—that's essentially what Python's built-in `int` type is already. Just use shift operators on `int` values. See the **Edit** in @Graham's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some module rules :

1) (a+b)mod(n)  = amod(n)+bmod(N)

2) (a.b)mod(n)  = amod(n).bmod(n)

So you can transform your equation into :

(x**2-2)%n ==> (x.x - 2)%n ==> (x%n).(x%n) - (2%n)

If n is always greater than 2, (2%n) is 2 itself.

solving (x%n) :

If x and n are always in 2**value ; if x > n then (x%n)= 0 is the answer and if x < n (x%n)=x

So the answer is either 0-(2%n) or x**2-(2%n)

Comment: These rules are incorrect, at least as written here. For example (3+4) mod 5 = 2, while (3 mod 5) + (4 mod 5) = 7. You need to replace "=" with "≡". Or, equivalently, add one more "mod(n)" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute (x ** y - z) % n
it will be equivalent to ((x ** y) % n - z) % n

Python pow function includes as optional parameter a modulo, as it is very often used and can be computed in an optimized way. So you should use:

```
(pow(x, y, n) - z) % n
```

Comment: it is not faster.

Answer (score 0):

OP says in comment : *it's slow because I assign x to the answer and I repeat the process*.

I try this :

```
x = 2**(1000*1000)
n = 2**(100*1000*1000)

import time
t0=time.time()
for i in range(6):
    x = (x*x-2)%n   
    t1=time.time()
    print(i,t1-t0)
    t0=t1

print(x<n)

"""    
0 0.0
1 0.4962291717529297
2 0.5937404632568359
3 1.9043104648590088
4 5.708504915237427
5 16.74528479576111  
True   
"""
```

It shows that in this problem, it's just slow because `x` grows, doubling the number of digit at each loop :

```
In [5]: %timeit  u=x%n
149 ns ± 6.42 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

the `%n` takes absolutely no time if `x<n`.